# CoreText - change text color when tapped

Tags: ios, core-text

I am using CoreText to draw text to my table view cells as I implemented the fast scrolling technique. Links in my text are a different color and respond to clicks, but I cannot figure out how to get the links to look like they are being clicked i.e. change color when tapped then change back. I have seen this in multiple apps, but not sure how it is done. Can this be done with CoreText or do I need to use something else?

I know this can be done with UILabels but that defeats the purpose of drawing text directly in the cell's content view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you want to change the color of the text, you need to send a -setNeedsDisplayInRect: to the view in which you are drawing the text.  In addition, set a variable corresponding to the text color.

When the view redraws and invokes your drawLayer:inContext:, make sure that  `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` is set to the correct color (based off of the variable you set) and redraw your text.

You can also use a similar technique but with the methods in UIKit/UIStringDrawing.h rather than Core Text.

Comment: So I'm assuming I call this method when the touch begins and then when the touch ends I redraw the text back to its original color?

Comment: Yep!  You can also use -setNeedsDisplay: to redraw the entire cell if you don't have the rect of the text link handy, but be aware that's going to result in more drawing (slower).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```html
<style>
    button:focus {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<button>Hello</button>
```

The focus pseudo class of **CSS** changes the CSS of an element when element is being **focused**

**Focusable** elements are `a`, `input`, `textarea`, `button`, `select`, `object`

In mobiles / tablets, when these elements are **tapped**, these will be focused and in this example, color of text in button will change to red.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes